# Error while trying to Iterate over List of Strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of form `(String,(Int,Iterable[String]))`. I am trying to check if the string "Bethan" is a part of the `Iterable[String]`. I wrote the following line in scala:

```
val disOneRdd = disRdd.map(x=> {if(x._2._2.contains("Bethan")) (x._1,(1,x._2._2)) else x})
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
value contains is not a member of Iterable[String].
```

How can I check if the string is present in the list or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to list:

```
val disOneRdd = disRdd.map(x=> {if(x._2._2.toList.contains("Bethan")) ... })
```

Comment: Thanks..What is the difference between List and Iterable.

Comment: `Iterable` is a trait which covers many types, many not having `contains` method. `List` is a class which has `contains`. You could choose other class which provides this method.